# Use Twitter profile picture in iOS app

Tags: ios, twitter, parse-platform

I am using Parse.com as my backend server for an iOS app.  I have fairly easily linked Facebook accounts with each of my PFUser's, but some of them have signed up with their twitter accounts.  How do I obtain their twitter profile picture to show in my app?

I have search a lot for a solution and it is very confusing as some methods seem to have been deprecated in the Twitter API.  I believe it has something to do with an http request, but I am also confused about how to execute that.  Is is synchronous or asynchronous?  Any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone asked this on the Parse forms here, with a complete code sample.
https://www.parse.com/questions/how-do-i-get-a-facebook-or-twitter-users-profile-picture

To summarise though, you need to make a request to Twitter's /user/show endpoint with the "screen_name" of the user. (https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/users/show) This will return the profile information of that user, including the URL of the profile image ("profile_image_url").

The Parse SDK provides a way to sign this request once the user has added her Twitter account.

```
NSString * requestString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/users/show.json?screen_name=%@", twitterUserNameOfAuthedUser];
NSURL *verify = [NSURL URLWithString:requestString];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:verify];
[[PFTwitterUtils twitter] signRequest:request];
```